# Rails 4 and route_translator gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, haml, rails-routing, rails-i18n

I am using the route translator gem to translate my routes, but I cant get to work it in the way I want.

So basically I installed the gem and inserted the routes into the

```
    localized do
    end
```

And now I have routes like this

```
    users_en GET    /en/users(.:format)                               users#index {:locale=>"en"}
    users_cs GET    /cs/users(.:format)                               users#index {:locale=>"cs"}
    users_de GET    /de/users(.:format)                               users#index {:locale=>"de"}
```

In my haml views I use link_to to navigate to a new page. English is my default language so my default route is user_path, but if I am on a page of a different language like /cs/home all the translations work (the text inside the t('word to translate') works, but the link does not get translated and if I click on it I get on the page /users and not /cs/users

How can I fix this?

I tried to put the locale inside the name of the variable **"users_#{locale}_path"** and then extract the value out, put I cant get an answer to how can this be done (now i have just a string, and my link looks like /users_cs_path).

So, my questions are: 
1. Am I doing this the wrong way?
2. How can I create a string in haml like **"users_#{locale}*path"*** and then use it as a variable name to get the value like: **"#{users#{locale}_path"}** (but yes, this does not work).

in my locale.rb I have

```
    # tell the I18n library where to find your translations
    I18n.load_path += Dir[Rails.root.join('lib', 'locale', '*.{rb,yml}')]

    # set default locale to something other than :en
    I18n.default_locale = :en
```

And in my route_translator.rb

```
    RouteTranslator.config do |config|
      config.force_locale = true
      #config.locale_param_key = :locale
      config.generate_unlocalized_routes = true
    end
```

Thanks.

Comment: Are you saying that the link has improper, not localized url, or it has improper text in it?

Comment: The url in the link is not localized. I am on the page http://localhost:3000/cs and the link url for the about page should be http://localhost:3000/cs/about_translation, but it is http://localhost:3000/about. Because I have about_path, but I should have about_cs_path in the link_to t('about'), about_path

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding this in `RouteTranslator.config`:

```
RouteTranslator.config do |config|
  config.generate_unnamed_unlocalized_routes = true
end
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!!!! That actually did the trick. But there was another problem. I was using the 3.1.0 version (the gem version available) and this version did not have config.generate_unnamed_unlocalized_routes. I just needed to download the version from github and add this.